# Como desativar link através do CONFIRM do JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Estou desenvolvendo minha primeira aplicação web, sendo ela um gestor de contas a receber e a pagar, e encontrei uma dificuldade quando me deparei com a necessidade de um CONFIRM do JavaScript para permitir ou bloquear a ação de dar baixa em uma conta a pagar.
Estou usando o PHP para enviar alguns dados através da URL para que a aplicação faça a baixa da conta e retorne à mesma página com os mesmos parâmetros de busca, como data inicial e final, e status das contas.

```
<a onclick="confirma()" href="valida_cpagar.php?registro=<?php echo $registro;?>&di=<?php echo $data_inicial; ?>&df=<?php echo $data_final; ?>&st=<?php echo $status; ?>&valor=<?php echo number_format($dado["valor"],2);?>">Baixar</a>
```

Esse é o link que estou usando. Quando as informações chegam na página "valida_cpagar.php", as alterações são feitas no banco de dados e através de um HEADER, retorna a página de contas a pagar com os mesmo parâmetros, como dito acima.

Estou tentando usar uma função JavaScript, mas obviamente está errada, porque não funciona.

```
    function confirma(){
        var conf = confirm("Você confirma a operação?");
        if (conf == true){          
            alert("Conta baixada!");
            location.href="valida_cpagar.php?registro=<?php echo $registro;?>&di=<?php echo $data_inicial; ?>";
        } else {
            alert("Operação cancelada!"); }
        }
```

Gostaria que se caso o CONFIRM fosse verdadeiro, a conta fosse baixada normalmente, e se caso fosse falso, somente um ALERT seria exibido e nada seria feito no banco de dados.

Sou iniciante em programação, e tudo pra mim tem sido novidade. Obrigado a todos que puderem ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

A ação natural de um clique em um elemento `<a>` é encaminhar o usuário à URL indicada no atributo `href`. Sendo assim, será natural que o usuário clicando sobre o link ele seja redirecionado para a página `valida_cpagar.php`.

Como você quer evitar o comportamento natural e controlá-lo manualmente através da função `confirma`, você deverá informar isso ao navegador com a instrução `preventDefault`:

```
function confirma(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // ...
}
```

Com isso você inibe o comportamento natural, prevalecendo o que você definir dentro da função.

Comment: Só que para isso é preciso passar o evento na função: `onclick="confirma(event)"`, senão a variável `event` em `function confirma(event) {` não terá nenhum valor.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode mudar a ancora para:

```
<a onclick="confirma()" href="javascript:void(0)">Baixar</a>
```

E deixar que o click faça a execução.